hvplot reset axis to range of selected data when using dropdown
When using hvplot, the range of the y axis is calculated from all the data, which means that if you use the "by" keyword to get a dropdown option, the axis does not change. If one variable in your data has a numerically much smaller range than another, then you can't see the values of the variable with the smaller range, it just looks like a horizontal line.
For example, I have time series data as an xarray dataset, where I'm displaying sensor values for multiple sensors on one graph. Each sensor reports a DAC value which is 0 to 3 billion, and a temperature which is 0 to 100. If I use the "by" mechanism to choose either DAC or temperature, the y axis always has a range of 0 to 3 billion, even when the temperature is being displayed, so the temperature look like zero.
I would like to have the y axis range reset whenever the dropdown option is changed.

The solution turned out to be to use a hook. However there are some gotchas:

The documentation is terrible so it was very hard to work out how to obtain the dropdown selection.
Updating the y axis range affected the next redraw of the graph, not the current redraw; this was solved by calling refresh on the graph, with some logic to prevent an infinite loop since refresh would call the hook again.
The padding option did not work in this case so I implemented that too.

current_attribute = ''

def hook(data, plot):
    global current_attribute

    selected_attribute = plot.current_key[0]
    if not isinstance(selected_attribute, str):
        return
    if selected_attribute == current_attribute:
        return
    current_attribute = selected_attribute
    filtered_data = data.sel(attribute=selected_attribute)
    try:
        min_y = float(filtered_data.min().item())
        max_y = float(filtered_data.max().item())
        y_range_extension = (max_y - min_y) * 0.01 if max_y != min_y else 1.0
        limits = (min_y - y_range_extension, max_y + y_range_extension)
    except ValueError:
        limits = (0.0, 1.0)
    plot.ylim = limits
    plot.refresh()


alldata.hvplot.line(by='sensor').opts(hooks=[lambda plot, element: hook(alldata, plot)])


